# Aws Api gateway/Lambda python dynamodb works with postman but doesn't with webpage

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda_function.py

```
import json
from dynamodb import put_user

def lambda_handler(event, context):

data = json.loads(event["body"])


username = data["username"]
age = data["age"]
name = data["name"]

put_user(username,age,name)
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,POST'
    },
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

and dynamodb.py

```
from pprint import pprint
import boto3

def put_user(username, age, name, dynamodb=None):
 if not dynamodb:
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-2')

 table = dynamodb.Table('UsersTable')
 response = table.put_item(
  Item={
        'Username': username,
        'Age': age,
        'Name': name
    }
 )
 return response
```

I have created an API gateway with a POST method that works (and puts an item in the dynamodb table) when I call it from POSTMAN.

However I can't make it work when I use my javascript fetch in my Flask server  (/static/script.js):

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let body_info = {
        "username" : username.textContent,
        "age" : age.textContent,
        "name" : Name.textContent
    }

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(body_info),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "Origin": origin2
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log('Request failed', err))
})
```

[Firefox Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HWLF.png)

I have been trying to debug the app and found out that if a comment the

```
put_user(username,age,name)
```

then the Firefox console doesn't show any errors and I get the
[response from the api gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1BhZ.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let body_info = {
        "username" : username.textContent,
        "age" : age.textContent,
        "name" : Name.textContent
    }
```

was an empty object because is was an input html, and the contect of that can be seen with a *.value* not a .textContent.

With that fixed, the fetch sent a valid body and the apigateway, lambda and dynamodb executed properly!

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a **CORS** error. Basically, your web browser is expecting the server to return the HTTP headers required by the CORS standard, and it's not doing so.

Make sure you [Enable CORS on your API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) and redeploy your API, then test again.

If your issue persists, you could try [Returning CORS headers from your lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#apigateway-responding-to-cors-preflight)